# Livestreaming Youtube

Tags: video, live, streaming

I have a Vlog on Youtube that I would like to stream live via LiveStream, but the quality looks like complete garbage. It's blocks and just all around not what it looks like in the browser. Does anyone know of a way I can boost the quality of these youtube uploaded recordings so I can stream them from LiveStream?

Comment: Do you have access to the original video file on your computer? If so, you can upload it directly to LiveStream for probably better results.

Comment: what do you mean by `"It's blocks"`?

Answer (score 1):

**What you are asking is extremely difficult without some very expensive and complex software and video studio equipment.** I learned some techniques in After Effects that were supposed to make an enlarged video look better (certain blurs and sharpeners, deinterlacing, etc) but I was NEVER satisfied with the results. Every technique made the enlarged version blurry or grainy. **These techniques I just mentioned do improve the quality somewhat, but does not magically or vastly improve the quality like what everybody expects expects (not saying you do but in general).**

It's would be easier for you just to **stream from Youtube Live since it can be set to automatically record and upload your stream** once its completed. **It does so in HD or at least matches the quality of the stream.**

**I also find Youtubes general stream quality to be much better than LiveStream's.**

**Here is the official Youtube user guide on how to setup live streams.** The guide little lengthy but it explains all the steps quite thoroughly.

[**http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=2474025**](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=2474025)

**Notice Step 1, Part 8 with information about recording the live stream.** Just remember that if your live stream is going to go over 4 hours, which in my opinion is tremendously long, you cannot use the recording feature. **If this is one of the rare events or streams that would go over that time limit** (maybe a huge concert or music festival) **then a solution would be to have an "intermission" where you stop streaming at 3 hours and 50 minutes just to be safe.** Then have a nice 10 minute break to do whatever you want!

One important thing to note when recording live streams with Youtube is that **you can't edit the recorded stream once it exceeds two hours.** This is kind of lame but I understand why it was necessary.

Additionally, **it would be a good idea to record a local copy using an HD screen and audio recorder.** In this answer **I listed a few popular examples of [screen recording software](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/is-there-a-decent-computer-based-multiple-video-stream-capture-solution-out-the/4933#4933).**

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't really make sense as it is now--the quality of your YouTube videos should have nothing to do with livestreaming.

If your camera takes good video to begin with and the videos look fine on YouTube, then the problem with livestreaming is going to be the upload bandwidth of your internet connection. If you don't have the bandwidth, the stream has to be highly compressed, and will look pixelated (block-y) as a result.

Comment: LiveStream doesn't stream with as good of quality as youtube does. At least IMO